# How to enable UAC for a delphi program?

Tags: delphi, manifest, uac, administrator

I enabled UAC from Project -> Options... -> Manifest
[image]

but when the UAC prompted

[image]

and I select "No", the delphi .exe will not run at all. It will only run if I select "Yes".

I would like to ask if there is a way around this matter? Doesn't matter if I choose "Yes" or "No", the delphi .exe will still run as it suppose to with / without Administrator privilege.

Comment: I suspect the following will work: Start the app normally, and during startup, attempt to create an elevated new process of the app. If this succeeds, let the original process simply exit; otherwise, let it continue.

Comment: Does your program need to run elevated or not? If it does then everything is fine. If not then use asInvoker. If some parts need elevation and some parts don't then you need to split up the program accordingly.

Comment: It sounds like you're coming at this problem with an incomplete understanding of what UAC is, what that dialog is asking, and why it is necessary.  Suggest a review of [How User Account Control works (MSDN)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works), with particular attention to the architecture section.  You are at the mercy of the user.  There is nothing your program can do to alter the user's preference for requiring (or not) UAC prompts for elevation requests.  In some case you can avoid it, in others not.

Comment: There is no *way around this matter*. It's working exactly as it is supposed to; if you say No, you're saying you do NOT want the application to run and make changes to your computer, in which case the application is not allowed to run. It's working exactly as designed, and exactly how you set it up to work.

Comment: Are you willing to run your application with elevated privileges without having the user prompted with the UAC dialog? That is not possible. Are you willing to run your application with elevated privileges if user grant it and still running without elevated privileges? Andreas gave you the way to do it in his comment.

Comment: The only other option to have an application granted persistent administrative privilege without needing the user to confirm is to install your application as a system service.  This would require administrative access to initially install only.  Things like the Mozilla Maintenance Service are an example of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elevation happens only at process startup.  A process cannot elevate itself dynamically once it has begun running.

To do what you are asking for ("Doesn't matter if I choose "Yes" or "No", the delphi .exe will still run as it suppose to with / without Administrator privilege"), you need to break up your program into 2 separate pieeces.

Have your main process run unelevated (Execution Level = "As Invoker") performing any tasks that don't require elevation.

Move your elevated tasks into either:

- a separate EXE (Execution Level = "Highest Available" or "Require Administration") that you can run when needed.
- a separate portion of your main EXE, ie invoked by command-line parameters, that you can run when needed using `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `"runas"` verb.
- a COM object that you can create and call into when needed using the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-com-elevation-moniker).